# promtail as service on windows behaves differently than run directly

Tags: windows, service, promtail

Somehow there seems to be a difference on how to run promtail on Windows.
[image]

Run directly via
`promtail.exe --config.file=config.yml` it works. It adds targets, and starts scanning:
[image]

Started via nssm as a service, service is running, stderr redirected to a file shows that promtail does never start the scanning, even terminates. Any idea what could cause this behaviour?
[image]

nssm settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]